# BeatifulSoup findAll is returning an empty array (python)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from this web page https://playruneterra.com/es-es/news and the part I am trying to get is this:

[image]

I am using BeatufulSoup to get the html and search in it but when I used the findAll method to get that line, it returns me an empty array. I tried the same in other pages and it works fine. What is happening?

This is my code:

[image]

This is an example that is working:

[image]

Thanks all.

Comment: instead of posting image of code, copy paste the code itself, it is more helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PyQt to build a headless browser and then scrape the data from the website. Here's the demo code for you:

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def main():
    page = Page('https://playruneterra.com/es-es/news')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    js_test = soup.find('h2', class_='heading-03 src-component-content-NewsItem-___NewsItem-module__title___3OcDj')
    print(js_test.text)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: I will try that

Comment: I had so much work and I couldn't try it earlier, but It doest work for me. js_test is empty

Comment: Strange. It's working on my end. Is there any error or something ?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `findAll` should be a dict, not a string.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it with the last modification I did and that worked in other pages.

Answer (score -2):

first right click and go into  view page source and search for the keyword you're looking for , if you can find your content there then you can use soup over it or else you can make use of selenium

And in the case of soup just Wrap classnames in dict format

```
title = soup.findAll('h2',{'class':'add your full classes here'})
```

Comment: this will not work as the soup library will download the page and then search for the tag. If the website is based on js framework then your solution fails.

Comment: If that's the case soup will never workout he have to headless browser tools like selenium